# Is it possible to use two querySelectorAll one inside the other in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a reaction system like Facebook but there is a problem I cannot figure out. So, let's explain how my html looks like. There is a main div that contains a link element **(`<a></a>`)** which is used for the default like icon to hover and open the reactions and a div that contains the reactions. Like you can see below:

```
<div class="post__actions-inner">
<div id="act-reactions" class="container">
<div class="content">
<div class="emoji">
<div class="hello">
<a class="emoticon-0" href="#/"></a>
<p>Like</p>
</div>
<div class="hello">
<a class="emoticon-1" href="#/"></a>
<p>love</p>
</div>
<div class="hello">
<a class="emoticon-2" href="#/"></a>
<p>Haha</p>
</div>
<div class="hello">
<a class="emoticon-3" href="#/"></a>
<p>Wink</p>
</div>
<div class="hello">
<a class="emoticon-4" href="#/"></a>
<p>Wow</p>
</div>
<div class="hello">
<a class="emoticon-5" href="#/"></a>
<p>Sad</p>
</div>
<div class="hello">
<a class="emoticon-6" href="#/"></a>
<p>Angry</p>
</div>
<div class="hello">
<a class="emoticon-7" href="#/"></a>
<p>Crazy</p>
</div>
<div class="hello">
<a class="emoticon-8" href="#/"></a>
<p>Speechless</p>
</div>
<div class="hello">
<a class="emoticon-9" href="#/"></a>
<p>Grateful</p>
</div>
<div class="hello">
<a class="emoticon-10" href="#/"></a>
<p>Celebrate</p>
</div>
<div class="hello">
<a class="emoticon-11" href="#/"></a>
<p>Heartbroken</p>
</div>
<div class="hello">
<a class="emoticon-12" href="#/"></a>
<p>Evil</p>
</div>
<div class="hello">
<a class="emoticon-13" href="#/"></a>
<p>Embarassed</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<a id="default-like-2288" href="#/" class="post__action post__action--reaction reaction reaction__toggle reaction-toggle--2288 reaction-emoticon-0 js-reaction-toggle" style="display: block;" data-id="2288">
<span>Like</span>
</a>
</div>
```

So, what I am trying to do is to show the reactions when I hover over the default like. I tried to use two querySelectorAll one inside the other but it didn't help in this problem. This is what I tried:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.post__action--reaction.container').forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
        var container = document.querySelectorAll('.container').forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
          container.style.display = "block";
        }));
      }));
```

What can I do to fix this problem? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all '.post__action--reaction.container' is not the correct selector. If you are trying to add event listener to your default like button, then you should be listeninig to '#default-like-2288' or just '.post__action--reaction'.

I am assuming you will have multiple default like buttons & containers. You can show and hide the .container elements using the following logic,

```
    let defaultLike = document.querySelectorAll('.post__action--reaction')
    
    defaultLike.forEach((like) => {
        //gets the previous sibling node which is also an element.
        //here, previous element sibling of the like  button is #act-reactions div
        let reactionContainer = like.previousElementSibling
        
        like.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {reactionContainer.style.display = 'block'})
        like.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {reactionContainer.style.display = 'none'})
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is a little over complicated. It looks like you have a consistent structure for the tags etc... so I would suggest just putting each set of `like button` and `emoji` inside of one container and using `querySelectorAll()` to grab each container.
You can iterate over each container and change the visibility of it's `children` by toggling classes.

I've included an example that I think takes a pretty simple and vanilla JS approach to this.

```js
let likeButtons = [...document.querySelectorAll(".likeButton")];
likeButtons.forEach(lb=>{
  lb.addEventListener("mouseover",()=>{
    lb.children[0].classList.remove("hidden");
  })
  lb.addEventListener("mouseout",()=>{
    lb.children[0].classList.add("hidden");
  })
  
})
```

```css
.content{
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  position:relative;
}
.likeButton{
  position:absolute;
  cursor:pointer;
  left:100%;
  top:100%;
  transform: translateX(-100%) translateY(-100%);
}
.emojiContainer{
  position:absolute;
  left:100%;
  top:10%;
  transform: translateX(-100%) translateY(-100%);
}
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>
  
  <div class='likeButton'>
  
  <div class='emojiContainer hidden'>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='content'>
  
  <div class='likeButton'>
  
  <div class='emojiContainer hidden'>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='content'>
  
  <div class='likeButton'>
  
  <div class='emojiContainer hidden'>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, I tried what you told me but still doesn't work.

Comment: @BradCruise There's a runnable and working code snippet attached to my answer lmao

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't help in my case. The html can't be changed from how it is structured right now